# <table> tags within <apex:repeat> working in Sandbox but not in Production

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat

Any reason why table, tr, td tags placed inside apex:repeat are visible on my Visualforce Page in Sandbox, but not in Production?

Can anyone offer some advice to get this working?

Sandbox

[image]

Production

[image]

Repeat Table Section

```
<div id="leftBlock">
            <apex:pageBlock id="dateSelection" title="Date Selection">
                <div id="properyRates">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!property_rate_list}" var="propertyRate" id="propertyRateList">
                        <div class="tableDiv">
                                <table class="propertyRateTable" value="{!propertyRate.Id}" onclick="return selectDate('{!propertyRate.Id}');">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <apex:outputText id="outputDates" styleClass="dates" value="{0,date,EEE', 'MMM'.'dd', 'yyyy}">
                                                    <apex:param value="{!propertyRate.Date__c}" /> 
                                                </apex:outputText>
                                                <input type="hidden" class="property_rate_name" value="{!propertyRate.Name} {!propertyRate.id}"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>               
                                    <tbody class="subText">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Housekeepers: </td>
                                            <td class="subTextResults">{!propertyRate.Housekeepers__c}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Properties: </td>
                                            <td class="subTextResults">{!propertyRate.Properties__c}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Notes: </td>
                                            <td class="subTextResults">{!propertyRate.HK_Notes__c}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>                                        
                        </div>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you post source code? I have feeling that I have seen that before and there are some static resources not updated on production

Comment: @kurunve Yes I will post one of the repeat sections

Comment: Maybe the data is just not there or you have no access to the data.

Comment: @kurunve I have edited my post to include the repeat section

Comment: @mast0r I do have access to the data on the physical objects, is there something I must do to enable the data on visualforce pages as well? Also shouldn't the CSS or something still be visible even without the data?

Comment: I think if there is no data the `<div class="tableDiv">` block will never be rendered. Try to check the data availability.

Comment: @mast0r I have enabled all of the data from the profile editor. Where can I check the data availability? and also where do I enable it if I haven't?

Comment: You should have access to the dev console. Just execute some SOQL's and get the potential values from the `property_rate_list`. Another way would be to access the data (records) just per Salesforce UI.

Comment: @mast0r Wow, you were exactly right. I re-read through the code, as it's been a while since I actually wrote it..and I realized that I simply forgot to create data that the application relied on. Thank you!! If you want to submit an answer, I will mark it as correct. Otherwise I can

Comment: In other words, you didn't do the proper "housekeeping" - ironic, no? :-)

Comment: LOL @crop1645 ...